# PocketSphinx android displaying results even without me speaking

Tags: android, pocketsphinx-android

I am using pocketsphinx on android for spotting a keyword, but it doesn't recognize any other keyword than the required one. Moreover it doesn't even wait for me to speak and displays the keyword in the logcat.

Here is my code:

```
public class SpeechService extends Service implements RecognitionListener {

private static final String TAG = "myTag";
private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
private static final String KEY_PHRASE = "hello";

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private PowerManager.WakeLock lock;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.shutdown();
    lock.release();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent data, int flags, int startId) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(SpeechService.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if(result == null)
                recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
        }
    }.execute();

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
    // of different kind and switch between them

    recognizer = defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))


            //.setRawLogDir(assetsDir)


            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)


            .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEY_PHRASE);
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    //Log.i(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    //Log.i(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
    if(!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH)) {
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "onPartialResult");
    if(hypothesis == null)
        return;
    String result = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    Log.i(TAG, "result = " + result);
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
}

@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "onResult");
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onError");
    recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onTimeout");
    recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
}
}
```

Here is the Logcat when I haven't even spoken yet.

```
result = hello
result = hello
result = hello hello
result = hello
result = hello hello
result = hello
```

and so on...

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Obviously, it is trying to start a conversation with you !!!   Just kidding :-)

Comment: hahaha.. Nice one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have too many false alarms you can reduce keyword threshold from 1e-40 to 1e-20 or even 1e-10 in this line:

```
        .setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)
```

Comment: `.setKeywordThreshold(1e-15f)` did the trick but not comletely. It won't listen on lower threshold. But anyway thanks.. :)

Comment: What's wrong with PocketSphinx? Even after setting setKeywordThreshold, it behaves so randomly, if even there is no input of voice it gives particular phrase values in onPartialResult and even if I speak particular phrase it doesn't give any result. I think it's totally waste of time with using this library with no accuracy at all.

Comment: What is threshold btw?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue too.

I think it is too easy to recognize "hello",So I changed the keyword to two words at first time.

But it was not good to use,because sometimes it couldn't recognize.

So I made my grammar by myself and used addGrammarSearch method. By the way your grammar can't not only be one word ,you have to add some words to cheat noise.

Final I wrote Judgement method to recognize keyword in onParticalResult or onResult method.

If you have any better answer i desire to know.

Comment: why we use grammar?